# what might be the reason that session value is not persistent between pages when programming php?

Tags: php, session

I am now using php session to store value and pass it between pages.

I make basic checks like making sure call `session_start()` on every page and check sessionid cookie is set in the browser, but the value is not persistent between pages.

For example, I set `$_SESSION["abc"]='abc'` on one page, but when i print it on another page, it is null.

I noticed that the corresponding cookie file is not created at the specified path when using file to store the cookie value. what might be the reason for the session file not being created?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['foo']))
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'hello';

var_dump($_SESSION['foo']);
```

If you load that page more than once, do you ever see the message `hello`?

If yes, then your problem has to do with your code, which means you probably destroy the session value somehow somewhere, but if the above does not work it might be that your `session.save_path` is not writable.

What does this give you?

```
<?php

var_dump(is_writable(ini_get('session.save_path')));
```

Comment: your help is very valuable! now i can make sure the problem is do with my code, there are many parts where it will do the exit(header($url)) logic. is this the problem?

Comment: Look at the response HTTP headers with Firebug/Webkit Inspector. Does the session cookie ever change? If not, then you are destroying the session value. To find out, I guess you just need to debug, go through the code, either with a debugger or just place `var_dump($_SESSION['foo']);` every here and there to determine when it has been lost.

Answer (score 2):

notice if you are destroying at the end of every page.Please remove it, Coz when you destroy the session on every page there is no persistency in session. Moreover if you are using some sort of logout code please destroy that session on that part of code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a directory name "tmp" in your server directory , it is used to keep the sessions temporary file , make sure that folder is  given the read and write access.

Answer (score 0):

you can change session path (if allowed) and set 0777 permissions
in .htaccess

```
php_value session.save_path  /home/your_domain.gr/public_html/tmp
```

also the error logs have anything?